# Why react calls function in subcomponents event when this subsomponents not rendered?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is the example

```js
const getResult = () => {
  document.getElementById('logger').innerHTML += "FUNCTION CALLs immediately";
  return 'RESULT string AFTER 3S';
}

const A = () => {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      {getResult()}
    </Wrapper>
  );
};

class Wrapper extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { active: false }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => this.setState({ active: true }), 3000);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.active && this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<A />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="logger"></div>
<div id="app"></div>
```

The question is - why `getResult` function calls immediately? `children` component in `Wrapper` should be rendered after 3s. But function calls immediately anyway. Why is so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically you *invoking* function and React treats a result of this function as `children` - `RESULT string AFTER 3S`. If would like to delay the function invocation you can invoke in when the `state` is changed.

```
const getResult = () => {
  document.getElementById('logger').innerHTML += "FUNCTION CALLs immediately";
  return 'RESULT string AFTER 3S';
}

const A = () => {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      {getResult} // remove immediate invocation
    </Wrapper>
  );
};

class Wrapper extends React.Component {
  ...

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        // here we can invoke children as a function, because we pass a function
        {this.state.active && this.props.children()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Then you'll get expected result. [`Worked example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/100215/)

Answer (score 0):

Because when the parser reads your file and executes it, the `A` component is immediately executed (and thus triggers the content of the `getResult` function), but its result (the `return` statement) is only displayed after the timeout.

Technically you already have in `this.props.children` the content of the `return` from `getResult` at first render, but you only display it after 3 seconds.

I don't know if it's very clear, it's not easy for me to explain it in english.

If you want to only trigger some code at render, you should place it inside the `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the `children` in your `Child` components are displayed after 3 seconds, but the **getResult** function is being evaluated in the parent. when the Parent renders.

The Wrapper components render function is called after the App components and remember getResults function is being executed by the parent App and not Wrapper component. It not the Child component that dynamically evaluates the children props when it needs them but the Parent evalutes it and pass it down to the child. The child may or may not decide to use it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Previous answers make sense, I just want to add that your code written in a way when child function is triggered **twice**! 
First time when you render A function and second when state is active and wrapper calls it again.

Check this [`link`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/100192/), I proved it here.
Hope it will help you to understand what is going on